# Applying a score to an object in a table using SQL and Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Trying to write a function to see how often an object exists and give it a + 1 based on the number of times it exists.

Using sqlite database and python.

```
select distinct Date, Name from history order by Date Desc
```

Will return:

```
Date        Name
2012-25-03     a
2012-25-03     b
2012-25-03     c
2012-25-03     d
2012-24-03     b
2012-24-03     c
2012-24-03     d
2012-24-03     e
2012-23-03     c
2012-23-03     d
2012-23-03     e
2012-23-03     f
```

Basically looking to accomplish the following in either python or sql:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 3
e = 2
f = 1
```

I have attempted a few different approaches in python using iterators and subqueries, but haven't been successful, maybe it can/should be done is sql.

Appreciate everyone's time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Name
     , COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM history 
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

If there is a chance you have more than one row with same `Date` and `Name` and you don't want to doubly count those rows, change the `COUNT(*)` to:

```
     , COUNT(DISTINCT Date) AS cnt
```

---

(update) If your SQLite version does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`, you could use a subquery in that case:

```
SELECT Name
     , COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
          Name, Date
      FROM history 
    ) AS h 
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy in SQL. You just need to use the `COUNT` aggregation function.

```
SELECT `Name`, COUNT(*) FROM `history` GROUP BY `Name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the count function in sql?  This is psuedo code...

```
counts = 
result = <query_function>("select distinct Name from history")
for result in results:
    result2 = <query_function>("select count(*) from history where Name LIKE ?", result.Name)
    counts[result.Name] = result2

for key,value in counts.iteritems():
    print '%s = %d' % (key,value)
```

Comment: This has to be the worst way to do this.

Comment: I appreciate it's nasty and results in a (potentially ridiculously large) number of DB queries, but I was trying to demonstrate the logic, not the most optimized answer.